# Replace outliers with column quantile in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
    A   B
0  92  65
1  61  97
2  17  39
3  70  47
4  56   6
```

Here are 5% quantiles:

```
down_quantiles = df.quantile(0.05)
A    24.8
B    12.6
```

And here is the mask for values that are lower than quantiles:

```
outliers_low = (df < down_quantiles)
       A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3  False  False
4  False   True
```

I want to set values in `df` lower than quantile to its column quantile. I can do it like this:

```
df[outliers_low] = np.nan
df.fillna(down_quantiles, inplace=True)

    A   B
0  92.0  65.0
1  61.0  97.0
2  24.8  39.0
3  70.0  47.0
4  56.0  12.6
```

But certainly there should be a more elegant way. How can I do this without `fillna`?
Thanks.

Comment: do you mind a one-liner: `df[~outliers_low].fillna(down_quantiles, inplace=True)`?

Comment: I thought that there should be more native pandas way to do this. And Nickil Maveli answer clearly shows it.

Comment: Yes I forgot about `mask`, I've upvoted Nickil's answer accordingly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`DF.mask()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method. Wherever there is a presence of a `True` instance, the values from the other series get's replaced aligned as per matching column names by providing `axis=1`.

```
df.mask(outliers_low, down_quantiles, axis=1)
```

[image]

---

Another variant would be to use [`DF.where()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) method after inverting your boolean mask using the tilde (`~`) symbol.

```
df.where(~outliers_low, down_quantiles, axis=1)
```

[image]